# How to buffer an AM signal?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, load, amplitude-modulation

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The above shows an AM modulator circuit which sums a sine wave and a triangle wave to produce an output which will undergo resonance using RLC to produce an AM signal.

The TL072 is commonly used in AM radios. LTspice with a TL072 buffer circuit does not show any waveform distortions on the buffer output even if I drive a high load (let's say 100 Ω.)

When I build the circuit in real life, the waveform is not distorted only if I use a 6 kΩ resistor.  Below 2 kΩ resistance, the waveform gets severely distorted.

The reason why I want the output current of the buffer to be high and not distorted is because it will be used in an RLC resonant tank which requires a reasonable current to operate to produce an AM signal.

What solutions can produce a low-impedance output which operates at a 200 kHz frequency? Note that the waveforms are made up of 200 kHz waves. I am dissapointed to see the severe distortions in real life when I use a 2 kΩ resistor as a load.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: One thing I've noticed is the diode placement. You know, I'm quite sure it's supposed to be after the output and before the LC tank. I did build a similar AM transmitter, but I didn't use a buffer. When the voltage is positive, the LC tank has a very high impedence at the carrier frequency. When the mixed voltage is negative, the diode is an open circuit, such that the LC tank once more has no effect on the mixer stage. Another option for a buffer is to use a simple BJT Emitter follower buffer with a 2N3904 transistor (but the BJT has to be DC biased). I personally also interested AM radios.

Comment: Why do you say the TL072 is commonly used in AM radios? Of the AM radios I’ve seen, it is unlikely that they would use a TL072. Can you give an example?

Comment: Also, the 200khz carrier is good, but for the mock audio signal on the other branch, I'm a bit confused as to why you happen to use two voltage sources. I would think a single AC source at 1khz would suffice.. but maybe I'm missing something. Anyhow, I too have an interest in AM radios and have built several even on breadboards (they worked great in the end, but it was tricky).

Comment: @ee_student, hi, since you have to measure the AM signal which is very tiny,less than 100mV normally which is sometimes limited by your oscillioscope, do you try to amplify it using an op-amp? Because I am trying to buffer my signal using TL072, and apparently the output does not really match the input well and get distorted.

Comment: Yes, in the context of a receiver, it's really is as small as that and sometimes smaller. You know, what I've done is used a Emitter Follower to buffer the antenna, the a Common Emitter to amplify, finally another Emitter Follower before the Envelope Detector stage. In a different model, I've skipped RF amplification all together, and only amplified the recovered audio with an LM386. It worked in my area, but the latter approach may not be enough if signal is weak. I suppose you may also use an Op Amp as amplifier (at least 20mhz Op Amp, ideally more).

Comment: I suggest to try the Op Amp first against a 1 mhz signal from a signal generator. You might already have a signal generator from the the transmitter (the 200 khz one). If it works against a 500 ohm load for example, then the Op Amp is fine. Usually Op Amps have a small DC output at their inputs. Maybe it's superstitious, but I'd put a capacitor (1uF - double sided, electrolytic), between the Op Amp positive terminal and the antenna, so DC from the Op Amp won't go into the antenna. To give a DC outlet, place maybe a 47k resistor between the positive terminal of the Op Amp and ground.

Comment: Since it's only up to 2mhz no impedance matching is needed. 47k is required not to load the antenna - the antenna input (AC) will go both through the 47k resistor and through the positive terminal of the Op Amp.

Comment: I can't edit - important Capacitor non electrolytic to allow positive \ negative charge on any direction. Normal Ceramic capacitor would be fine.

Comment: For the transmitter, I believe you could do without a buffer. Main issue seems to me would be the diode placement which needs to be before the LC tank and after the Op Amp output (if an Op Amp is used to buffer, which I'd think is not needed really for the transmitter). If an Op Amp is not used, once more the diode has to be before the LC tank, after the mixer.

Comment: A bypass capacitor is simply a cap between the power rail of the breadboard (pin adjacent to positive voltage 12V pin where the DC voltage source goes in) and the ground of the breadboard. Between 0.1uF and 10uF are good choices.  It's important to have to avoid noise, but I don't think that's the issue though (really knowledgeable people, more knowledgeable than me, but hadn't worked with breadboards for a long time, so they keep worrying about them, but really even at 2 mHz it's usually fine, at least in my experience).

Comment: Your op amp is not powered correctly. You have a positive voltage applied to the negative power rail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's is a simple amplitude modulator:

[image]

The amplitude of the 1 MHz carrier wave is from -2V to 2V (simple AC signal generator.)

The amplitude of the audio signal (simulated as a 1 KHz AC source) is from -1V to +1V (either a real audio source or an AC signal generator.)

The diode is a 1N4148.

For a different carrier frequency, the LC tank values would have to be recalculated.

The TL072 has a bandwidth of only 3 MHz.

If you place it before the diode (important not to place the diode before the op amp,) the frequency of the carrier can be 300KHz at the most. A frequency of 200KHz like in your design is reasonable.

The image is taken from a book called: *From Resistor to Radio* by Daniel Chermetz (6th edition.) It's about AM radios, but it's focused on BJT transistor design (2N3904) so it might not perfectly match your interests.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. I have simulated your circuit in LT Spice, but did not get beautiful AM signal? I posted my pic above :)

Comment: Oh but the picture is perfect - an AM wave corresponding to the 1 KHz AC wave. I rather believe this is what an AM wave should look like. By the way, this thing with the bypass cap., somebody mentioned is just a 0.1uF to 10uF capacitor between the power rail of the breadboard (pin adjacent to the pin which takes the battery voltage) and the ground of the breadboard. Nice to have against noise.

Comment: One small thing: you used a 1 MHz pulse like in the schematic. But it should preferably be a Sine wave. The author of the book wanted to show that it works even with square waves from a 555, but if you have a Sine wave then all the better.

Comment: By the way, an AM wave has to be synmetrical. Any kind of non-symmetrical result is a mix \ summation, but not real modulation. (The output looks great, but just to double check the the carrier wave is 1M?).

Comment: Probably TMI by now, but basically an AM wave is the 1 MHz AC wave with high amplitude where the 1 KHz audio is high, and low amplitude where the 1 KHz audio is low. And the result matches that. I wonder what in particular did think is not correct with the obtained result?

Comment: This image shows an AM waveform (for reference): https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/amplitude-modulation

Comment: @ee_student, did you actually built this circuit in real life haha :) ? It's really kind of tricky to get it to even see the tiny AM signal on scope

Comment: Yes, very similar in 2019, and the 1 KHz AC source was replaced with analog input from my phone playing YouTube. I apologize, but I have some doubt whether you quite fully understand what is an AM signal. The signal is at 1 MHz. Its peaks are at 700 mV and its mins are at nearly  0V. When it's at 700 mV, the 1 KHz audio signal is near its peak (1V). When it's at 0 V, the 1 KHz signal is near its min (-1V). And in between for intermediate values between the peaks. The amplitude of the result has to vary based on the amplitude of the 1 KHz AC signal.

Comment: Oh if the concern that it looks like a blob, you could zoom in horizontally to see the individual 1 MHz cycles. It's too zoomed out to see individual sinusoidal cycles. But the keys is the blob pattern over time, not the individual cycles.

Comment: Hi, take a look at this at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHiWJ2lxSqI&ab_channel=KnowledgeAmplifier   , it gives an extremely nice AM signal with large amplitudes and can be easily detectable by scopes in real life. Probably gonna build this.  What do you think?

Comment: Sounds good. There is a thing called modulation index. At a good modulation index when the audio is low (-1V), the modulated signal has to be about 0V. Here the modulation index is not so good, maybe 15% difference in amplitude between peaks and troughs. Also the video was with very low frequencies, so try to simulate realistic frequencies. Lastly, there is DC bias which is expected, but it means that under the LC tank, there has to be a capacitor + resistor to ground. The debiased voltage would be seen across the resistor.

Comment: One suggestion: you have a plot above the modulated signal in blue. On the same graph please add another plot of the 1MHz signal and the 1 KHz audio source. This way you'd see how they relate. Back to the video, in general, this is a class C amplifier. It has some amplification, but is more noisy that the passive one above. PS I'm usually not that helpful I really like the topic of radios, and I went through a journey with that, so if someone is also interested, I try to help. But it's because I like radios.

Comment: Oh you've done the simulation of the other circuit - great. And it has better modulation index than on YouTube but still not great. Only advice I can think of: R4 should have some resistance probably. Voltage can be 9V. Slightly better transistor is the 2N3904. To prevent DC current into the AC source, I'd put a capacitor after R1. The audio source, in parallel with R4 also behind a capacitor and a small resistance.

Comment: As such need to be a bit careful about DC currents into your AC sources. That's not ideal. That's why the passive circuit is safer. To be honest, I'm still not sure, why do you think the result from the passive circuit is incorrect? (PS - if you put a capacitor after R1, R3 can be increased a bit and R2 reduced a bit to maintain the old DC bias). Good luck.

Comment: thank you for answering so detailed!!! Well, the waveform in your circuit I simulated is not so nice as compared to the one from youtube haha. :) . I am actually trying to build an AM walkie talkie and I am quite new to electronics, not in my studies haha

Comment: Very last point - honest: the little spike things all over the top is not the AM. It's less than linear modulation. The smoother it is the better. The modulation is three hills and two valleys in the green plot.

Comment: Hi, sorry for coming back to this question again, about the resistor + capacitor to the ground to give a de-biased DC voltage, is it done as shown in the above pic I updated and highlighted in green, what would be those values :) ?  Thank you :) Do you mean that when it is de-biased, the output AM signal will oscillate around 0V as the input signal is an AC about 0 V also?

Comment: Cap first then resistor in a series. Cap at least 1uF. Not in parallel.

Comment: @jessicasmith - Hi, You tried to edit this answer, to add a schematic. Edits to answers by someone other than their authors, must not change their meaning. Adding a new schematic changes the meaning, so I rejected the edit. There is a technique for adding an image link in a comment. However it seems you have already got an image link, as you have uploaded what looks like the same schematic into your question (but without any visible explanation in the text). Please be careful not to use this site like a forum. Clarification of answers should be done in comments, not in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your insight, such as simple way to de-bias a signla. Jeez, last time, I didn't know this method so I solve it by making the offset to the origin using a voltage divider with an additional battery haha which is more workl :)

Comment: @jessicasmith thanks for your last comment. Earlier in the thread there may have been some doubt whether it's possible to build radios in real life on breadboard.
Here's a video of a radio I built:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CJi93dBBUJ0
I built various AM radios quite a number of times.
But it's quite tricky, tips:
1. First time use LM386 as amplifier
2. Put a 10uF capacitor between ground and positive rail
3. I like batteries more than power supplies (less noise?). But maybe it's just a prejudice.
4. Sometimes randomly adding resistor \ moving wire helps.

Comment: In the end of the video, I prove that it works by turning on and off the battery a few times :)